# Difference between find and grep -l

Tags: linux, command-line

If I want to **list files** by date containing "foo" in the file name, I can do either of the following
`find . -name "*foo*" -exec ls -lrt {} \;`
`ls -lrt $(find . -name "*foo*")`

If I want to **list files** by date containing "foo" inside the file itself, I can only do
`ls -lrt $(grep -rl "foo")`

Also, `grep -l` returns a list of files, for example
`file1`
`file2`
`file3`
And the list will be a different colour than default colour

Wheras `find` returns a list, in the default colour, like this
`./file1`
`./file2`
`./file3`

So what's going on here? What's with the difference between the two results, and why can't I exec the result from grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two proposed commands are not equivalent.  If you use `find` to `-exec ls`, what happens is that `find` will run `ls` once for each file.  The output order will be
the order found by `find`, not `ls`.  Because `ls` is being run one-file-at-a-time, it doesn't know how to line up the columns.  For example, done here in Cygwin bash:

```
Nicole@NicoleDesktop ~/HamiltonCshell/Current/util
$ find . -name "s*.c" -exec ls -lrt {} \;
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 104826 Dec 29  2010 ./Archive/su.2010-12-29/su.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 107074 Aug  2  2011 ./Archive/su.2011-08-29/su.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 125359 Jul 17 11:47 ./sed.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 15517 Oct  6  2011 ./setrows.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 8454 Oct  8  2011 ./setwin.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 39007 Jan 24  2012 ./shortcut.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 4655 May 22  2009 ./showdesk.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 66906 Nov 20 09:58 ./sort.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 9702 May 22  2009 ./split.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 21306 May 22  2009 ./strings.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 113680 Jul 15 06:56 ./su.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 10076 May 23  2009 ./sum.c
```

If you use command substitution, the shell will paste the list produced by `find` back onto the command line as arguments to `ls` and then it will run `ls` exactly once on the entire list of files and result will indeed be ordered by date, newest first.

```
Nicole@NicoleDesktop ~/HamiltonCshell/Current/util
$ ls -lt $(find . -name "s*.c")
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None  66906 Nov 20 09:58 ./sort.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 125359 Jul 17 11:47 ./sed.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 113680 Jul 15 06:56 ./su.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None  39007 Jan 24  2012 ./shortcut.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None   8454 Oct  8  2011 ./setwin.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None  15517 Oct  6  2011 ./setrows.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 107074 Aug  2  2011 ./Archive/su.2011-08-29/su.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None 104826 Dec 29  2010 ./Archive/su.2010-12-29/su.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None  10076 May 23  2009 ./sum.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None  21306 May 22  2009 ./strings.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None   9702 May 22  2009 ./split.c
-rwx------+ 1 Nicole None   4655 May 22  2009 ./showdesk.c
```